# I can't update/install plugins on my wordpress ERROR

Tags: php, wordpress

i can't update/install plugins on my wordpress : To Perform the requested action, Wordpress need to access your web server. Please enter your FTP credentials to proceed. If you do not remember your credentials, you should contact your web host

Comment: You could try `define( 'FS_METHOD', 'direct' );` in your wp-config file

Answer (score 0):

This error usually happens the Web Server's user (www-data in Apache, for example) doesn't have the right permissions over the files that is trying to modify.

You can solve this issue by granting the right permissions to the Web Server's user.

> **Run the following commands ONLY if all files within your wordpress directory are supposed to be PUBLICLY available, and you have clear what your Web Sever's user and group are.**

Running `ls -l` from your Wordpress root directory will show you the current ownership state.

> **These commands can't be undone, and can break your site if used incorrectly.** You need to know what you are doing.

`chown -R <web_server_user>:<web_server_user_group> <wordpress_root_folder_path>`

If you suspect that your directories and files permissions might be incorrect, you can also run:

```sh
find <wordpress_root_folder_path>/ -type d -exec chmod 0755 {} \;
find <wordpress_root_folder_path>/ -type f -exec chmod 0644 {} \;
```

Answer (score -3):

cd to your wordpress location and run this command

> sudo chown -R www-data:www-data *

on your terminal. This resolved my issue

Comment: This is simply dangerous advice. We have no idea whatsoever about their server setup, so the web server user and group might have totally different names. Naively executing this could stop the whole site from working.